# ORMLite where clause using in

Tags: java, android, ormlite, where-in

I have a question regarding ORMlite [`Where#in`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#in%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Iterable%29). Basically I would expect this to accept a list of ORM mapped beans and use their ids in the clause. However it does not seem to do that.

If I pass in a `List<Long>` as second argument, the list containing only the ids, everything goes well.

If I pass in the list with the original `Element`s I get:

```
 getElementFromDatabase() / No element with properly properties with this id in DB.
 getElements() / Can't get elements.
 java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `_id` IN (com.mypackage.myapp.database.Element@417ff150 ) 
  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:184)
  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:65)
  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:247)
  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:196)
  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:265)
  at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:361)
  at com.mypackage.myapp.presentation.DatabaseManager.getElements(DatabaseManager.java:248)
  at com.mypackage.myapp.presentation.DatabaseManager.getElementsByState(DatabaseManager.java:305)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
  at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
  at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
  at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
  at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
  at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
  at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
  at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
  at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `_id` IN (com.mypackage.myapp.database.Elements@417ff150 )
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1542)
  at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.BasicApiCompatibility.rawQuery(BasicApiCompatibility.java:15)
  at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:180)
```

The class `Element` contains the following:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Constants.TABLE_ELEMENTS)
public class Element implements Serializable
{

 @DatabaseField(columnName = Constants.COL_ELEMENTS_KEY_ID, id = true)
 private long _id;
```

Can it be something with the annotation. Am I using the method as expected?

**EDIT** The requested both pieces of code:

```
List<Element> elements =....;
where.in(Constants.SET_ELEMENTS_ID, elements);
```

This above throws the exception in the first version of the question.

```
List<Element> elements =....;
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (Element element: elements) {
    ids.add(element.getId();
}
where.in(Constants.SET_ELEMENTS_ID, ids);
```

Works as wanted, but is cumbersome.

Comment: You are passing objects instead of ids. So you need to update code where you pass `elements`. Like write a utillity method to calculate all ids from elements.

Comment: @PankajKumar This is not a good answer neither a good explanation. I expect a good ORM to do that for me. Hibernate does it.

Comment: Hey I was just giving you an idea. Didn't aware that you were looking for ORM like Hibernate in Android. If you implemented equals() of your model then your code will work..

Comment: @Gray Hi, nice to see you. I think I misunderstood the description given in docs. Honestly I was guessing that it should work lite that. But ORMLite is your baby so you know better, how it works. Please add an answer. And please add more description into docs... Looking for a nice answer :)

Comment: I think the "cumbersome" answer is the right one.  How would ORMLite know that when you pass in a collection of X you really meant to pass in a collection of x.id?

Comment: @Gray I was waiting for you to join in :). My thought was that `Where#eq` in case of working on foreign key allows you to pass in an annotated bean and it automagically concludes I am speaking of its id. Why shouldn't the `in` method behave in similar fashion then?